# How I can Move directory from one location to another in SFTP storage laravel 9

Tags: php, sftp, laravel-9

I want to move files from one directory to another on SFTP storage.

I have tried this:

```
$file = new Filesystem();
$moved = $file->moveDirectory($from, $to);
```

but I need the full path to directory but with the following SFTP
code it is not working:

```
$full_path_source = Storage::disk('sftp')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix('batch_1');
```

config->filesystem.php

```
 'sftp' => [
            'driver' => 'sftp',
            'host' => env('SFTP_HOST'),
            'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('SFTP_PASSWORD'),
            'prefix'=>'/var/multilabel/batchprocessing_images/'
        ],
```

mycontroller

```
function upload(Request $request){
        $dir = 'batch_'.$number;
        $tmp_input_path = 'tmp/'.$dir.'/input';
        $tmp_output_path = 'tmp/'.$dir.'/output';

        $path = $dir.'/input';
        $output_path = $dir.'/output';

        Storage::disk('sftp')->makeDirectory($tmp_input_path);
        Storage::disk('sftp')->makeDirectory($tmp_output_path);
        Storage::disk('sftp')->makeDirectory($path);
        Storage::disk('sftp')->makeDirectory($output_path);
    

        foreach (request()->file('files') as $key=>$image) {
           Storage::disk('sftp')->put($tmp_input_path,$request->file('files')[$key]);
         }
         $from = 'tmp/'.$dir;
         $to = $dir;
         $moved = Storage::disk('sftp')->move($from, $to);
}
```

above code moves empty directories

How I can do this with filesystem movedirectory method

Answer (score 0):

This is oddly very vague and surprisingly it cannot be found in Laravel Documentation nor API, but the `Storage::move` function is not only for files, **but it will work on directories as well:**

```
Storage::move($oldDirectoryPath, $newDirectoryPath);
```

**To get the path of your file , You can simply call:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
 
$path = Storage::path('file.jpg');
```

**File Paths**: As found in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-paths

> You may use the path method to get the path for a given file. If you are using the local driver, this will return the absolute path to the file. If you are using the s3 driver, this method will return the relative path to the file in the S3 bucket:

Comment: @soniyakukreja what error do you get? please provide more information in your original post to help further understand

Comment: Thanks for reply
I have already tried this 

Storage::disk('sftp')->move($oldDirectoryPath, $newDirectoryPath); 

but this don't move sub folders or files inside the directory as I'm using sftp so its not giving me URL , path function returns the absolute path to the directory

Comment: My task is to upload the images on server via sftp in laravel so that 
path is /var/multilabel/batch_1/input